# Showing that two given graphs are homeomorphic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

I won't to verify whether the two graphs given above are homeomorphic. I am not sure of the method to verify this. I would much appreciate if anyone could give some assistance. Thanks

Comment: Topologically, you've got two concentric circles, and two line segments from the inner circle to the outer circle.

Comment: @bof interesting observation. But I would like to use a more simpler method maybe through reduction/ subdivision

Comment: Let's see. The graph on the left has 4 vertices of degree 2. Erase the dots, and you're left with 4 vertices and 6 edges: vertices a and b joined by 2 parallel edges; c and d joined by 2 parallel edges; single edges ac and bd. (Why didn't you label the vertices in your picture?) Now process the graph on the right in the same way. You've got vertices a',b',c',d' and edges a'b',a'b',c'd',c'd',a'c',b'd'. So the original two graphs were subdivisions of isomorphic multigraphs.

Comment: Hint: they're both bipartite.

Comment: @bof Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil How can I use these being bipartite to prove that both are homeomorphic?